# MySQLSyntaxErrorException when using COUNT with DISTINCT

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get an error with the below sql statement. The sites that I have visited advocate this as the correct way to use these 2 keywords together. I am trying to get the number of unique traits in the results from a test. Name is the PK for the test.

```
public int getTestCount(Database db, String name) throws SQLException {

    int count = 0;
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Trait) As Count FROM RESULTS WHERE name = ?";

    PreparedStatement ps = db.con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, name);

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        count = rs.getInt("Count");
    }
    return count;
}
```

Error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
>       near 'DISTINCT Trait) As Count FROM RESULTS WHERE name = 'test3'' at line 1

Comment: please specify the error you get

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT Trait) As Count FROM RESULTS WHERE name = 'test3'' at line 1

Comment: Please add this error to the content of the question and not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space after the word `COUNT`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Trait) As Count FROM RESULTS WHERE name = ?
```

Here is a live example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bf483/1)

Comment: Brilliant! Can't believe I was beat by something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getTestCount(Database db, String name) throws SQLException {
    int count = 0;
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Trait) As T_Count FROM RESULTS WHERE name = ?";

    PreparedStatement ps = db.con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, name);

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        count = rs.getInt("T_Count");
    }
    return count;
}
```

Count is reserved. So you can define any valid variable and use it when you call with `rs.getInt(<< here >>);`
A good link for your reference: [MySql Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)